# window.location does not fire every time

Tags: javascript, window.location

I would like to know why this function I wrote only fires about 70% of the time. I would like a set of bullet points to change depending on where you navigated from

```
 function navigatedFrom(currentURL) {
     if(currentURL != oldURL){
              oldURL = currentURL;
              let url = window.location.href.split("=");
              console.log(url[1]);
              if (url[1] == "asset_tracking" ) {
               return (
                   <div>
                     <p className="txt-li">Track assets on maps in real-time</p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Route intelligently with the Navigation SDK
                     </p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Increase revenue by optimizing fleets
                     </p>
                   </div>

                );
              } else if (url[1] == "use-cases_store-locator" ) {
                return (         
                  <div>
                     <p className="txt-li">Help customers find stores, places, and people on maps</p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Take location search on-the-go
                     </p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Add unique functionality to stand out & drive sales
                     </p>
                  </div>

                 );
              } else if (url[1] == "use-cases_turn-by-turn-navigation" ) {
                return (         
                  <div>
                     <p className="txt-li">Fully integrate navigation in your app</p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Route with smarter live traffic
                     </p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Customize the look and feel
                     </p>
                  </div>

                 );
              } else if (url[1] == "use-cases_data-visualization" ) {
                return (         
                  <div>
                     <p className="txt-li">Make informed decisions with geospatial data</p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Build maps presenting data in new ways
                     </p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Create heatmaps, isochrones, choropleths, and 3D maps
                     </p>
                  </div>

                 );
              } else if (url[1] == "on-demand-logistics" ) {
                return (         
                  <div>
                     <p className="txt-li">Build custom in-app navigation for drivers</p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Optimize complex itineraries
                     </p>
                     <p className="txt-li">
                       Improve routing with live traffic
                     </p>
                  </div>

                 );
              }
          }
          oldURL = window.location.href;
          setTimeout(function(){ 
        navigatedFrom(window.location.href);
      }, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location fires inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120353/window-location-fires-inconsistently)

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout is not an ideal way to do this. It may work like you want it if you use an eventListener instead of setTimeout. You could try to listen for the popstate event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) and see if it helps.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```